# How to respond the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: vue.js

i am one day old in vue and i am facing a problem with a 404 code. I am trying to implement vue as frontend, django as back end and some of the routes are still not implemented. I have written this script inside my SignUp.vue

```
<script>
    
    import axios from 'axios'
    import {toast} from 'bulma-toast' 

    export default{
        name : 'SignUp',
        data(){
            return {
                username :'',
                password1 : '',
                password2 : '',
                errors : [

                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submitForm(){
                this.errors = []
                if(this.username === ''){
                    this.errors.push('The username is missing')
                }
                if(this.password1 === ''){
                    this.errors.push('The password is too short')
                }
                if(this.password1 !== this.password2){
                    this.errors.push('The passwords are not matching')
                }

                if(!this.errors.length){
                    //this is an object that sends data to the back end
                    const formData = {
                        username : this.username,
                        password : this.password1,

                    }
                    axios
                        .post('/api/v1/users/', formData)
                        .then(response => {
                            toast({
                                message: "Account was created, please log in",
                                type: 'is-success',
                                dismissible:true,
                                pauseOnHover: true,
                                duration: 2000,
                                position: 'bottom-right'
                            })
                            this.$router.push('/dashboard')
                            return response
                    })
                    .catch(error =>{
                        if (error.response){
                            for (const property in error.response.data){
                                this.errors.push(`${property}: ${error.response.data[property]}`)
                            }
                        }
                        else if(error.message){
                            this.errors.push('Something went wrong. Please try again!')
                        }
                    })

                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Every time i try to sign up it gives my an error like this:`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. The error list in web page shows me a strange error like this:

```
0: <

1: !

2: D

3: O

4: C

5: T

6: Y

7: P

8: E

9:

10: h

11: t...
```

Ihave tried to restart my chrome and clear cache but still i have not solved it yet. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

I guess by now it is not possible to give you a "solution" as you're not giving enough information to solve your problem.

Except if you misspelled the path to your API (/api/v1/users/) I think the problem actually come from your API. Either your "rewrite rule" in "urls.py" or file alike, or the function that it calls is wrong. Check syntax on [docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/).

And, passing by, you're "strange error" is just caused by your loop on the string error.response.data, so I would suggest to just push the data without loop, or to use the following:

```
.catch(error => {
  if (error.response) {
    if (typeof error.response.data === "String") {
      this.errors.push(error.response.data)
    } else {
      for (const property in error.response.data){
        this.errors.push(`${property}: ${error.response.data[property]}`)
      }
    }
  } else if (error.message) {
    this.errors.push('Something went wrong. Please try again!')
  }
})
```

In conclusion, if you can't find the problem in your API or in a misspelling mistake, you can still add your django content in your question, to make it more complete.

Answer (score 0):

It seems he API has not been implemented, or you are not calling the correct endpoint in django.

Thus django is simply returning the default 404 html page as a response; which is a string or `text/html` format. and your error block:

```js
for (const property in error.response.data){
  this.errors.push(`${property}: ${error.response.data[property]}`)
}
```

is simply parsing it out as a array of characters in the format `<index>: <char>` as using `for .. in` with an array will give you the indexes of the elements in array